# how to check presence of a number in a structure field?

Tags: matlab

This is my code where a structure is formed:

```
while (count < 98)
    % certain codes here, then

    s(count).frame = count;        
    s(count).freq = frequency;
    s(count).str = strength;

    binnum = find(newdata2);
    s(count).bin = binnum;

    count = count + 1;
end
```

The content and length of the array `binnum` is uncertain as it forms within a loop and changes its values in each iteration. I know that 'binnum' can hold values only between 1 to 1024.

Now I need to check this field `s.bin` vertically i.e. from `s(1).bin` to `s(97).bin` each time for the presence of numbers from 1 to 1024. i.e. first 1 is present in which all `binnum`s the corresponding frame values I need to store in another structure. If for example `1` is present in `s(1).bin` and in `s(70).bin`, then I have to store the values 1 & 70 in another structure.

Again the same thing to see for 2 then 3 then 4 and so on upto 1024, i.e. each time I have to go through `s(1).bin` to `s(97).bin` to check for 1 alone then for 2 alone then for 3 alone and so on.

I have tried something like this

```
xx = 1;  
for bins = 1:1024  
    for frame = 1:97
        if (s(frame).bin == bins)  
            r(bins).start(xx) = frame;
            xx = xx + 1;
        end  
    end
end
```

but this wont work because in the `if` condition I am unable to index `s.bin` since I dont know its length.

What shall I do now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem and suspect there's an easier way to attack this. That said, is this what you're after?

```
r = [];
for bins = 1:1024
    r(bins).start = [];
    for frame = 1:97
        if any(s(frame).bin == bins)  
            r(bins).start(end+1,1) = frame;
        end  
    end
end
```